# Query Multiple Tables in Django and geta consolidated result

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I am building a Blog application in Django and currently stuck at Querying the Data. I am creating a Post and then uploading multiple images to that post.

This is my Blog Post Model.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)   
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000,null=True)
    Tags = models.CharField(max_length = 255,null=True,blank=True)
    Created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    Updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

And this is my Images Model

```
class Images(models.Model):
    Post = models.ForeignKey(Post,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
```

Now using this implementation I have 2 tables in DB in which data is stored as expected.
In the first tables all the details related to Post are being stored and in the second Table ID, Post_Id, Image_URL is being stored. If I upload 3 images then three rows are being created.

Now I want to Query the data that is -> I want all the posts and I want all the Images according to the Posts.

I can get seprate queries for Post and Images but how can this be done in Django ORM?
How can I query The data?

Comment: Can you share how you want to use all this data? The ORM provides things like `prefetch_related` for reducing the number of queries, it depends on what related data you want and how you use it

Comment: So I want to use the title, Description, Tags, category for the Post model and the Images URL from the Images Model.

Comment: Its better to give attributes of classes as `snake_case` instad of caps first. Python recommends to use Capsfirst only to class names.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a view that populates a context variable named `posts` with a queryset like `Post.objects.all()` your template could look something like this simplified

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.category }}
    {{ post.description }}
    ...
    {% for image in post.images_set.all %}
         {{ image.image.url }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Every time you iterate over `post.images_set.all` you will execute another query, you should use `prefetch_related` so that you don't perform a query each time and the data is cached

```
    posts = Post.objects.prefetch_related('images_set')
```

Comment: Can you please let me know the solution if I was using Ajax request to get the result instead of using template.

Comment: @TusharSethi Are you using the rest framework?

Comment: Yes in additon to the template engine. I am using AJAX to load certain areas of the website.

Comment: So here I would need an array of objects of Posts with their respective Image Urls in the Post Object.

Comment: Without knowing what your API or serializer looks like it's hard to say, something similar to the above would probably work though

Comment: Alright. I will figure that one out. I just have one more question as I am new to the DJango. So You used Prefetch_related but how does the naming convension works in django? like images_set ? how will I come to know about others?

Comment: @TusharSethi the docs have a good explanaition https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects. When you have a ForeignKey from another model a reverse relationship is created, by default it's named `<model_name_lowercase>_set` but this can be overridden by passing `related_name` to the ForeignKey

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this;

```
post = Post.objects.all().prefetch_related('images_set').get(pk=1)
images = post.images_set.all() # this will bring you all images related to 
                                post
```

Comment: here in this case, since model is named as "Images" you should use `post.mages_set.all()`